# Normalize wheelEvent in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

How can i normalize window scroll event in `Firefox`?

This one works fine on `mousewheel` in `Chrome` and `Safari` browsers, but not in `Firefox`

```
var normalizeWheelEvent = function(event) {           

   if (!!event.wheelDelta) {

      var wheelDeltaRate = 10;
      event.wheelX = event.wheelDeltaX / wheelDeltaRate;
      event.wheelY = event.wheelDeltaY / wheelDeltaRate;

   }

}; 

target.addEventListener('mousewheel',normalizeWheelEvent, useCapture);
```

How can i update `event` to normalize `mousewheel` in firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firefox you need to use `e.detail`, something like this:

```
if (!!event.detail) {

    // Similar to your wheelDeltaRate, detailRate will change the speed
    var detailRate = 1.20;
    // let's add some magic for scrolling
    event.wheelX = event.axis == event.HORIZONTAL_AXIS ? (-1 * event.detail) * detailRate : 0;
    event.wheelY = event.axis == event.VERTICAL_AXIS ? (-1 * event.detail) * detailRate : 0;
}
```

and don't forget to use:

```
target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',normalizeWheelEvent, useCapture);
```

let me know if it works for you